# Determine the range of a function is open or closed or both etc.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Suppose $f,g:R^2→R^2$ are continuous functions, where g is surjective. Determine if the following sets are open, closed, neither, both or if it can't be determined.
>
> $1. (f+g)(B(0;1))$
>
> $2. (f+g)^{−1}({(x,y):x>0})$
>
> $3. (f∘g)^{−1}({(1,2)})$
>
> $4. g^{−1}(R^2)$
>
> $5. g^{−1}(B(0;1))$

---

Then i checked the definitions $\dots$ and a Theorem

> Def open ball
>
> $B(a;r)=\{x∈R^n:|x−a|<r\}$.
>
> Def interior
>
> $S^{\circ}=\{x∈R^n:∃ε>0:B(x;ε)⊆S\}.$
>
> Def boundary
>
> $∂S=\{x∈R^n:∀ε>0:B(x;ε)∩S≠\varnothing  \wedge  B(x;ε)∩S^c≠\varnothing\}$.
>
> Def closure
>
> $\overline{S}=\{{x∈R^n:∀ε>0,B(x;ε)∩S≠\varnothing}\}$.
>
> Def
>
> $1.$ A set S is open if $S=S^{\circ}.$
>
> $2.$ A set S is closed if $S=\overline S.$
>
> Theorem $5$
>
> Assume that $f$ is a function $R^n→R^k$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> $1.$ $f$ is continuous.
>
> $2.$ For every open set $U⊂R^k$, the set $f^{−1}(U)={x∈R^n:f(x)∈U}$ is open.
>
> $3.$ For every closed set $K⊂R^k$, the set $f^{−1}(K)={x∈R^n:f(x)∈K}$ is closed.

---

By Thm.$5$ $f,g:R^2→R^2$ have the following:

$1.$ cannot determine

$2.$ should be open

$3.$ it's just a point, which should be closed

$4.$ both

$5.$ Since $g:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ is continuous

Take the open ball $B(0;1)$ which is a proper subset from $domain(g)$

Then $(g)^{-1}(B(0;1))$ is open

I checked the answer, this is correct.

My question is $\dots$ is $1.$ cannot determine (by Thm.$5$) or it's just cannot determine?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1$ take the function $g(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ so the image of the open ball is open.

Now take the function  $g(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=(1,1)$

Then the image of the ball is $\{(1,1)\}$ which is a closed set.

So you just cannot determine.